# How to make flask extensions support i18n?

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a app which using flask and some extensions like flask-peewee, flask-wtf, etc.. The problem is, I want to translate strings in these extensions into Chinese, how to modify these extensions to support i18n?

I know flask-babel can make app support i18n, but it didn't support i18n of other modules, especially extensions of flask.

And I don't want to directly change strings in these modules, because it's a dirty way.

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask-wtf` form already support i18n, it supported by default next locales https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/tree/master/wtforms/locale, and you always can add missing.

I don't find any information about `peewee` i18n support, but I also don't found any language specific messages there.

For `wftpeewee` I found only support `gettext` usage in code without translation files, so you can just try translate this few strings in main application or update `wtforms` translation files.

For `flask-peewee` I don't find any support in code and templates, so look like you will fix this yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I have made a fork and create a Chinese translated branch for flask-peewee. wtforms is well i18n supported.